# Why return 4 value when want just 1 for my query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this query for get a value from a table:

```
SELECT     
    AssemblySite, AssemblyPlannedDate, AssemblyDate, 
    ShippmentPlannedDate, ShippmentDate, DelayMotive, 
    LogisticsResponsable, HasBOM, HasSerialComponents, 
    PrototypeComponents, ReadyForAssembly, OrderPriority, DeliveryTime, 
    RequesterApproval, ApprovedDate, PlannedFinishYear, PlannedFinishWeek, 
    Designer, RawMaterial, SpecialMaterial, TestArea, DesignHours, 
    Temperature, TestType
FROM         
    Orders_Header
WHERE     
    (DVMOrderNumber = '%15078702%') 
    AND (Status = 'Completely Defined') 
    OR (Status = 'Assembly') 
    OR (Status = 'Post-Assembly') 
    OR (Status = 'Document review') 
    OR (Status = 'Delivery approval') 
    OR (Status = 'Shipping')
ORDER BY 
    AssemblyPlannedDate
```

I have column `DVMOrderNumer` and I want a value, more specific is this: `SO-15078702`. But when I search my value with this query return 4 value.

More specific:

```
SO-15078702, SO-15078703, SO-15078704, SO-15073792-08
```

Where am I going wrong? I want to get just one value from my table. The `DVMOrderNumber` has more stats like Assembly, Post-Assembly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will be executed in following order

```
((DVMOrderNumber = '%15078702%') AND (Status = 'Completely Defined')) OR
  ((Status = 'Assembly') OR
  (Status = 'Post-Assembly') OR
  (Status = 'Document review') OR
  (Status = 'Delivery approval') OR
  (Status = 'Shipping'))
```

You need to use proper `Parenthesis` to filter properly. Try this where clause

```
WHERE  ( DVMOrderNumber Like '%15078702%' )
       AND ( ( Status = 'Completely Defined' )
              OR ( Status = 'Assembly' )
              OR ( Status = 'Post-Assembly' )
              OR ( Status = 'Document review' )
              OR ( Status = 'Delivery approval' )
              OR ( Status = 'Shipping' ) )
```

OR Use `IN`

```
WHERE  ( DVMOrderNumber Like '%15078702%' )
       AND Status IN ( 'Completely Defined', 'Assembly', 'Post-Assembly', 'Document review',
                       'Delivery approval', 'Shipping' )
```

Comment: @Vladut - Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You query is probably not being parsed the way you want.  So, learn to use `IN`:

```
WHERE DVMOrderNumber like '%15078702%' AND 
      Status IN ('Completely Defined', 'Assembly', 'Post-Assembly', 'Document review', 'Delivery approval', 'Shipping')
```

Your original query is parsed as:

```
WHERE (DVMOrderNumber like '%15078702%' AND Status = 'Completely Defined') OR
      (status = 'Assembly' OR
       . . .
      )
```

That is, the status is only tied to the order number for the first comparison.  You could, of course, fix your original query using parentheses, but `IN` is a cleaner method.

Comment: 0 results, when i use "in"

Comment: DVMOrderNumber = '%15078702%' => DVMOrderNumber Like '%15078702%', thanks a lot